# SpringData neo4j node property not populated

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a simple relationship (Account)-[IdentifiedBy]->(Identity), defined like this

```java
@RelatedTo(type = "IDENTIFIED_BY", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
private Set<Identity> identities = new HashSet<Identity>();
```

When I load the Account and access its identities, all the identities are loaded, but all their properties except for ID are null. However, if I annotate the property with @Fetch, then the identities are loaded correctly, with all properties. Is this by design or am I missing something?

```java
@NodeEntity
public class Account {
    @GraphId Long nodeId;

    @RelatedTo(type = "IDENTIFIED_BY", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    //@Fetch
    private Set<Identity> identities = new HashSet<Identity>();

    public Set<Identity> getIdentities() {
        return identities;
    }

    public void setIdentities(Set<Identity> identities) {
        this.identities = identities;
    }
}

@NodeEntity
public class Identity {
    @GraphId Long nodeId;

    private String identifier;

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }
}

public interface AccountRepository extends GraphRepository<Account> { }

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/test-context.xml"})
@Transactional
public class AccountTests {

    @Autowired
    protected AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Test
    public void accountMustLoadItsIdentities() {
        Account acct = accountRepository.save(new Account());

        Identity id = new Identity();
        id.setIdentifier("merlin");
        acct.getIdentities().add(id);
        accountRepository.save(acct);

        acct = accountRepository.findOne(acct.nodeId);
        id = acct.getIdentities().iterator().next();
        assertEquals("merlin", id.getIdentifier());
    }    
}
```

The unit test fails on the last assertion, but succeeds if @Fetch on Account is uncommented.

Comment: This is by design. If you want relationships to be eagerly fetched, you'll need the annotation. If you don't want to use the annotation, take a look at advanced mapping mode in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
account.getIdentities()
```

you should do something like the following:

```
this.neo4jTemplate.fetch(account.getIdentities())
```

Not using the @Fetch keyword does not automatically enable lazy loading. To lazy load your properties use the Neo4jTemplate as plotted above.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design

> We try to avoid loading the whole graph into memory by not following relationships eagerly. A dedicated @Fetch annotation controls instead if related entities are loaded or not. **Whenever an entity is not fully loaded, then only its id is stored**. Those entities or collections of entities can then later be loaded explicitly using the template.fetch() operation.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#reference:simple-mapping

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is in simple mapping mode. In advanced mapping node, the properties will be loaded when accessed if I understand it correctly.